# Use function with simple tooltip jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, tooltip, jquery-tooltip

I have this function create for me for called tooltip :

```
<script>

function tooltip(texto) {

    $(document).ready(function(){   
        $("a#toolshow").easyTooltip({
            tooltipId: "easyTooltip",
            content: ''+texto
        });
     });
 }

</script>

<style>
#easyTooltip { padding:5px 10px; border:2px solid #93C0D2; background:#000000; color:#FFFFFF; width:auto; font-family:Arial;
font-size:12px; }

#easyTooltip2 { padding:5px 10px; border:2px solid #93C0D2; background:#000000; color:#FFFFFF; width:auto; font-family:Arial;
font-size:12px; }

</style>



<a href="#" id="toolshow" onmouseover="javascript:tooltip('Área de
Consulta Seleccionada');" class="op_links_select"><b>(?)</b></a>
```

The function i create for use with the plugin easy tooltip works fine the problem are 2 :

1) The Tolltip no show inmediatly when i go over the link , i need put over the link other time for show tooltip

2) The tooltip show many times no one time , when i go over the link i see the tooltip 3 times , and i don´t understand why , i want use this plugin for easy tooltips in this way because it´s the best for me i can call javascript function from the link and send my own text as i want , but i have these problems , if you can tell me something about i tell you thank´s from this moment for your help :)

The best Regards for all , Thank´s